# How can I speed up Lubuntu running from USB thumb drive

Tags: usb, lubuntu

I'm running Lubuntu 14.04.3 LTS (32bit) from USB thumb drive since my HDD is dead.
How can I copy/move data to RAM to speed up system performance? 
It is full installation not the live, and there is no swap. I have 3GB of RAM.

Comment: Did you search this site for "optimize usb"?  There are lots of suggestions.

Comment: Try `sudo sysctl vm.swappiness=10` which will set the system to place everything in RAM except to leave 10% free. So it will put everything it can there. Try that for a little bit and let us know and, if it works, I'll write up an answer.

Comment: 'sysctl vm.swappiness=10' had no effect on my system. RAM load also stayed the same.